# I am getting an error since I tried to move into this function csvDownload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- I am trying to download the file from the grid.
- when I click open first window link a popup opens.
- in that popup you will see a grid.
- but right now I am getting an error since I tried to move into this function

> csvDownload Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

- I am trying to download the file like the sample prototype fiddle.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it providing my code below

sample prototype
http://jsfiddle.net/khfL1jsh/

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < not working
>   http://jsfiddle.net/2s79mnq5/

```or-tag-here
template: function csvDownload() {
        //return "testing" + that.FinancialDocuments.ImageType(model);
        <a id=\"sportsDataPlayer\" download=\"download.csv\" type=\"text\/csv\">#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"
        var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
        var data = new Blob([csv]);
        var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");
        alert("I am here");
        a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      }
```

Comment: At a first see I can see some typos, the object you're trying to pass to the as the template is bad formatted and not a valid one.

Comment: When you attempt to get the element by id, the element is not on the DOM, it would not work as you're thinking.

Comment: @halbano hey but I don't see the link in the grid...I mean this value '1 Download CSV ...when you click open first window link----------> jsfiddle.net/wL4v15vd/2

Comment: Let's chat if you want!

Comment: @halbano yeah sure..if you click open first window you will see a pop up... in this you will see two columns.... like tat it should show in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khfL1jsh/

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the JS file a bit and now at least is not firing the error.

Take a look:

```
$("#open1").click(function() {
  $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
    width: "500px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 1"
  });
});

//debugger;

$("#open2").click(function() {
  $("#win2").show().kendoWindow({
    width: "500px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 2"
  }).data("kendoWindow").center();
});

$("#close2").click(function() {
  $("#win2").data("kendoWindow").close();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pai-del-menu').hide();
  var cnt = 0;
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: [{
        FileName: '1 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots1'
      }, {
        FileName: '2 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots2'
      }, {
        FileName: '3 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots3'
      }, {
        FileName: '4 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots4'
      }, {
        FileName: '5 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots4'
      }],
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            FileName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            ThreeDots: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      sort: {
        field: "FileName",
        dir: "asc"
      },
      pageSize: 10
    },
    height: 500,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
      field: "FileName",
      title: "File Name",
      //template: "<a id=\"sportsDataPlayer\" download=\"download.csv\" type=\"text\/csv\">#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"      
      template: function csvDownload() {
        //return "testing" + that.FinancialDocuments.ImageType(model);
        var htmlString = "<a id=\'sportsDataPlayer\' download=\'download.csv\' type=\'text\/csv\'>#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"
        var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
        var data = new Blob([csv]);
        var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");
        alert("I am here");
        a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);

        }, 
      field: "ThreeDots",
      title: "Last Name",
      template: "<span class='deleteRow'>ThreeDots</span>"
    }]
  }).data("kendoGrid");


  //var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
  //var data = new Blob([csv]);
  //debugger;
  //var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");
  //alert("I am here");
  //a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);


  // grid.tbody.parents(".k-grid-content").eq(0).kendoScroller({ useOnDesktop: false });

  // Start by hiding the confirmation
  $('.testingConfirmation').hide();

  // Create a persistent value for the window
  var testingWindowVal;

  // Listen to save button click
  $("#save").click(function() {
    // Set the persistent value
    testingWindowVal = $("#fname").val();

    // Show the dialog
    if (testingWindowVal) {
      $('.testingConfirmation').show();
    }
  });

  // Listen to yes from the confirmation
  $('#deleteDocumentYes').click(function() {
    // Update necessary things
    grid.dataSource.add({
      "FileName": testingWindowVal,
      "ThreeDots": "Last Name"
    });
    $("#fname").val('');

    // Remove the value
    testingWindowVal = null;

    // Hide the dialog
    $('.testingConfirmation').hide();
  });

  // Listen to no from the confirmation
  $('#deleteDocumentNo').click(function() {
    // Remove the value
    testingWindowVal = null;

    // Reset the #fname
    $("#fname").val('');

    // Hide the dialog
    $('.testingConfirmation').hide();
  });
});
```

This is the updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2s79mnq5/#&togetherjs=CVveJp1NKp

Comment: hey but I don't see the link in the grid...I mean this value...when you click open first window link---------->     http://jsfiddle.net/wL4v15vd/2/

Comment: I mean this value '1 Download CSV